# Matching unversioned sources against git repository

Tags: git

I have a legacy project, also containing sources for several open source libraries. Unfortunately, some of the libraries are simple snapshots without any revision information. 
I am looking for a way to identify the matching commit in the libraries repositories (git-driven).

What I've been doing so far, is some kind of mental 'bisecting' changes of single files, but these files are moved often between commits and following turned out to be rather difficult.

Preconditions, that could be utilized:

- an exact match exists
- some heuristic time interval information is possibly applicable
- the projects are not too big (<100kB C++ code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do the following:

1. Clone the repository of the library
2. Overwrite the working tree with the version you have at hand
3. Run `git diff` against all commits:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   for rev in $(git rev-list --all)
   do
       if git diff --exit-code $rev &> /dev/null
       then
           echo $rev
       fi
   done
   ```

Even if there is no exact match, this procedure can be easily enhanced to search for the revision with the least differences from your version.

Comment: A very good template. Because it turned out, that my first precondition wasn't true, I had to modify a bit. But after that, I was able to spot the correct answer easily: `git diff --exit-code --shortstat $rev `